# How to rotate mask around cursor?

Tags: animation, keyframes, masking

I want to animate the mask (half circle) in image editor - by rotating the mask around the cursor placed in the center, but the final animation looks strange.

[image]

Is this one of the limitations of the mask keyframe or is there anything that I can do better to create a simple rotation?

(I tried to add the last anchor point of a previous circle in a hope that it will be calculated as a circle shape, but it gave the same result.)

Thank you

Comment: What are you looking to use the mask for? It would be possible to rotate the mask at the compositing stage depending on your intentions.

Comment: The reason the rotation looks odd is because each vertex is moving to it's next keyframe in a straight line.

Comment: @Ray Mairlot: improve my workflow :) I will use it in VSE, I can rotate mask strip there, I just wanted to know if I missed something or it works like that.

Comment: @gandalf3: Oh, now I see ... Thank you. So it keyframes control point position. It does not keyframes trans/rot/scale  of whole mask. My fault.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by @RayMairlot you can rotate the mask in the compositor by addong a rotate node and animating its values:

[image]

Comment: I think it would have been courteous to at least suggest that I post my comment as an answer first, before answering yourself. See: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/436/what-to-do-with-questions-which-have-been-answered-in-comments