# How to rotate a mask in blender (Vfx not sculpting)

Tags: masking, motion-capture

Within blender I was doing some vfx and got to the masking stage, It was going well till I wanted to rotate it, and I couldn't.

I intended to rotate it because certain parts the thing I'm masking it doesn't change it just rotates.

I pressed `R` on the mask and it didn't do anything.
I've already looked through google and other similar questions.

Before pressing `R`

[image]

After pressing `R`

[image]

Comment: Already tried that @susu

Comment: Can you share the file?

Comment: I cannot share the file. (Yes I know the images don't transfer over and how to lock tracks)

Comment: I can rotate a mask in a new file, but I have to admit if you will want to keyframe this rot it doesnt work as you probably  expact anyway, for more check here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39344/how-to-rotate-mask-around-cursor

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the origin point was set to individual point not median point.

Which can be switched here at the top

[image]

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. But please, next time don't crop the images so tight, it's hard to help without information.

Comment: Ok next time I'll add larger images with more information