# Rotate mask in video editing blender

Tags: video, masking

Hi I have created a mask like this in my blender 3.3
[image]

So we can see the mask is surrounding the horse and its head is on the left side. And later, the horse head is on the right:
[image]

So how do I rotate the mask ?? I have read this question here about rotating [How to rotate a mask in blender (Vfx not sculpting)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185221/how-to-rotate-a-mask-in-blender-vfx-not-sculpting)
so I tried that and changed the origin point to mediant point, but that doesnt solve my problem. I still can't rotate my mask head horse to the right.
Thank you

Note:
This is the whole blender screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Please add an image of the whole Blender screen (via Window > Save Screenshot in Blender). At the moment we have no idea what we're looking at or where that mask has come from!

Comment: I edited the question and add the whole blender screen shot :-)

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar with Blender's VFX editor so someone else will have to answer that one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working in a 2D plane, rotation happens in the Z axis only, not X and Y.

[image: rotation]

What you can do instead is scale the mask on the X axis to -1, which will effectively mirror it on the X axis.

To do this, select your mask with <kbd>A</kbd>, then hit <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd><kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd>

[image: negative scale]