# Mask Image Plane in Shader Editor or Compositor

Tags: shaders, compositing-nodes, masking

I have an image as plane imported in Blender 2.91:

[image]

Now I want to mask off the red wine and then animate it so it would fill the glas:

[image]

Yes, it must be solved in Blender.

Tried it in Compositor with Set Alpha node, but the size of the mask does not fit and the alpha is not correct. Not to mention that I can not figure out how to bring this into shader editor...

[image]

Any help very very welcome.

### Edit:

lehuan5062 had the idea to solve it with a shader:
https://blenderartists.org/t/mask-roto-texture-of-image-plane/1278656/4

But still, animated masking in shader editor??

Answer (score 5):

### Boolean Modifier

Since you will have to separate lines of glass from red wine and white line on wine surface (that has to be part of animated section), seems to me easier to recreate pictogram in some vector app (so you can work with always sharp and clean shapes), import as SVG and animate with Boolean Modifier.

- add the glass *Solidify* modifier to get thickness, it will prevent from z-fight, or bring this object a bit above
- convert wine object (named *Wine_Mask*) to mesh and give it a *Solidify* modifier to get thickness (needed for later boolean operation)
- add a *Plane* to use it as a wine, split face into two, upper part for white wine surface line, the rest as wine volume, add *Solidify* modifier with less thickness than Wine_Mask object
- add *Boolean* Modifier *> Intersect > Object* *- Wine_Mask*

[image]

It can be animated in similar way as shader version too.

[image]

---

### Shader

Shader controlled by Empty

- keeps wine surface horizontal (independent on glass rotation)
- volume controll
- parented to glass keeps location

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Roto-Mask

From what I know it's the worst way ever to do something like this. Mask's shape can be animated by simply pressing <kbd>I</kbd> in *Image Editor*, but in a very limited way. From UI point of view there is not any feedback that key framing is happening, so open *Dope Sheet Editor* to to see them. The biggest issue is that animated points of mask transit along shortest way from key to key (see [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/39344/2214)). It isn't such a big problem to animate straight point movement, but curvy part would has to be animated frame by frame = time consuming.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this solution, pretty cool!
However, imagine using Blender as an AE replacement, I would still like to know how to roto textures.

Comment: There was also the idea to solve it shader wise: https://blenderartists.org/t/mask-roto-texture-of-image-plane/1278656/6

Comment: Sure, shader is fine I just preferred curves since it is scaleable without caring about image source resolution. Yet I'm not sure why to use roto-mask, that is harder to animate and also hard to re-adjust if needed. If you need you can use camera output merge in compositor or in VSE as well. Anyway, you solved it with shader, right? Or do you have still a question? It would be also nice if you can create your answer here with shader solution. Thanks

Comment: I'd still like to know how to use and animate masks on an image texture, this could be helpful for further ideas I have in mind!

Comment: @linuxmarc explore also the UV mapping node, see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6942/compositing-video-layers-in-3d-space

Comment: Thanks for the edits!! great answers...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of the community, the current solution to solve the wine is using shader nodes with a map range and a texture with a glas full of wine and one without wine.

[image: shader]

[image]

see blend file:

https://blenderartists.org/uploads/short-url/4prveEYzpwiD9OONGNXiTXJTiCy.blend

This is a solution, but still wondering how to create an animated mask on an image texture.